# Transition of Java SE Module from Netbeans 6.5.1 to 7.0

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, sdk

I have two versions of netbeans installed on my windows 7 PC i.e. 6.5.1 and 7.0. Java Module is installed in 6.5.1 and c/c++ in 7.0 . I want to transfer java module from older one to newer one but unable to find any help on Google.

Actually, I want to install java ME SDK 3.0.5, which requires netbeans 6.9 or higher. I have very slow internet connection, so, It will take long time to download it from internet connection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the old module will work with the new version of netbeans. Just go to tools->plugins and install the Java plugin and hit accept to the additional required dependencies that it will need. It may take time, but it will get there.